# Button Position in CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I Recently try out the div with expand and collapse. Everything works perfect. Here is the fiddle with I make the bar as fixed with expand and collapse button whenever i increase the font size of the div then the button doesn't comes with the div proportionally. Here is the fiddle what i am expect clearly. 
http://jsfiddle.net/vicky081/GyG3w/1/

```
   .btnn
        {
            width: auto;
            height: auto;
            cursor:pointer;
            background-color:#02adea;
            position: absolute;
            border:solid;
            margin-left:3%;
            border-color:#ffffff;
            border-top-color:#02adea;
            top:36px;
            text-align: center;
            padding-top: 7px;
            color:white;
        }
```

You can see that button comes outside the div. Is there is a way to show the button which is attached to the div even if i change the font size.

Any suggestion would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: @kangoroo Both of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a `top` value of `100%` the button is always stuck to the container whatever the font-size.

See it live http://jsfiddle.net/LeBen/UCTgR/ (I also added a CSS Normalize)

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(".text").hide();
$(".btn").click(function(e){
    var txt=$(this).html(); 
    var flag = txt==="open";
    if(flag){
      $(".text").show();
      $(this).html("close");
    }
    else{
      $(".text").hide();
      $(this).html("open");
    }        
});
```

});

```
.banner{
font-size:1.2em; 
position:fixed;
width:100%;   
}
.text {
background:#02adea;
text-align:center;
width:100%; 
}
.btn{
background:#02adea;
border:5px solid white;
border-top-color: #02adea;
color:white;
text-align:center;
width:2em;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GyG3w/5/

I suppose this is the effect you wanted, in this you can change the fixed div's font size as much you want, the rest of the elements' will be resized accordingly and the layout will be preserved

Answer (score 0):

You can use `bottom: -49px;` instead of `top: 36px;`